# How can I get multiple checkbox values in angular?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angular, typescript

How can I get multiple checkbox values and store the checked values in an array in angular?

here is my HTML code

```
<form >
<div class="form-check" >
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="admin"/>
  <label class="form-check-label" >Admin</label>
</div>
  <div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input"  type="checkbox"value="user">
    <label class="form-check-label" >User</label>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit"> assign role</button>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand all, you can do this:

**HTML**

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
  <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" formControlName="userCheck1" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" formControlName="userCheck2" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" formControlName="userCheck3" />
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
<button (click)="reset()">Reset</button>
```

**Code**

```
export class AppComponent {
  form: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      userCheck1: new FormControl({ value: true }),
      userCheck2: new FormControl({ value: true }),
      userCheck3: new FormControl({ value: true }),
    });
  }
  submit() {
    console.log(this.form.value);
  }
  reset() {
    this.form.reset();
  }
}
```

If you click submit, you get an array with all three options (`false` or `true`).

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-reactive-form-conditional-checkbox-disa-wwuea7?file=src/app/app.component.ts) is the Stackblitz.